# Qlikview Fast Change option is not working

Tags: qlikview

I have created one QV report in which i have added one chart which shows result data.

In that chart properties i have tick fast change allowed type as: Pivot table and Straight table.

My QV desktop version is 12. While selecting one dimension and one measure and click on change the type,at that time it is not working.

I have created my another report in QV version 11 and fast change is working proper over there. Is this the issue of versioning?Or else some property issue?

[image]

After clicking on the red highlighted symbol, it still keeps as it is and does not converting to pivot data.

Straight Table:

[image]

Pivot Table:

[image]

Also below is the Screenshot of the report which i have created in QV version 11. For one dimension and measure,while click on fast change option, it is converting to pivot table as per below:

[image]

Can anyone help me out please?

I have already tried by deleting my existing chart and created another new chart with same properties but it is also not working for the new one.

Comment: Are you able to share screenshots?

Comment: attached the SS.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still not sure what you expect. A pivot table with one dimension and partial sums at the top looks almost identical to a straight table. Which functionality are you looking to change between the 2? I'll add my screencaps as an answer

Comment: Can you add another dimension to that chart and show us the straight table vs pivot table view?

Comment: @TheBudac  attached the image of straight table vs pivot table after adding another dimension.

Comment: Also, i have attached the ss of another report in which the pivot table is working proper and that report i have created in QV version 11.

Comment: The charts with 2 dimensions are switching between Straight and Pivot. If you are expecting a dimension across the top then you can just drag the dimension you want to that position. But as far as I can see that is working as designed.

Comment: Thank you for informing about this, i was not aware about it but can you please tell me the steps of how to drag and drop the dimension at that position when only one dimension is selected?because i have tried but not able to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the title of the dimesion and drag it up and to the right. your cursor should go off of the object without releasing the mouse button. to about where my green arrow is.

[image]

Then it will look like this

[image]